# how to refresh the whole tabpanel in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tabpanel

I am using richfaces and jsf.

I am using `<rich:tabpanel>` to create the tabs.

I have taken 4 tabs.

In 1st tab , one refresh button is available. If I click that button, the whole tabpanel is refreshed. whatever the data is kept in tab2, tab3 and tab4 will be clear.

Comment: you'll have to accept some answers on questions of yours.

Answer (score 0):

use `<a4j:support reRender="tabPanelComponentId">` inside your button, or use `<a4j:commandButton reRender="tabPanelComponentId" />`

Comment: i think this is only for 1st tab refreshment.is it?

Comment: i need ,If click CLEAR button in 1st tab , then refresh the 4 tabs.is it possible

Comment: i used <redirect/> command in faces-config.xml. everything is working fine.

Comment: I am involving the 2 modules.

Comment: goto 1 module select the tab1 ,navigating through 1..3 tab.then Iam stoping my process.click the 2nd module.then again i selct the 1st module.now it is showing 3rd directly. i want to show the 1st tab.how ?